# Using GeoPandas to generate shapefile from GeoJSON for opening in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: shapefile, geojson, arcgis-pro, geopandas

I got from an API a layer of parcels in format GeoJSON, just like the file in this .zip

- https://www.dropbox.com/s/5eqi8bbqt6ej6lc/json_data.rar?dl=0

I need to convert this to a shapefile that  could be open for the ArcGIS Pro  desktop app

I used Geopandas to generate this shapefile.

```
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.read_file("data.json")
gdf.to_file("data.shp", encoding='utf-8')
```

This generates the shapefile

```
.
├── data.cpg
├── data.dbf
├── data.prj
├── data.shp
└── data.shx
```

I check with QGIS and works OK.

But when trying to open with ArcGIS Pro I got this issue
[image: A column was specified that does not exist]

I also checking other questions here I change the way  to save the field, in order to fix that, but I still  got the same issue.

```
gdf.to_file("data.shp", encoding='utf-8',  crs = {'proj': 'latlong', 'ellps': 'WGS84', 'datum': 'WGS84', 'no_defs': True},  driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

Here the shape generated by my code:

- https://www.dropbox.com/s/a95wk8oywoyb5om/data_shp.zip?dl=0

Comment: Is ArcGIS Pro not capable of opening a GeoJSON?

Comment: @Stefan good question I'm checking Arcgis desktop but I didn't see a way to add geojson file

Comment: This is not a legal shapefile. The dBase contains two "Shape_STAr" and one "Shape_STAe" field. The field naming is not legal ('.' is not permitted), and the duplicate name isn't either.

Comment: @Vince you think that this issue comes from Geojson file or is because of the code in python using Geopandas?

Comment: I don't know the source of the error, I just know the output is invalid. ArcGIS can certainly generate data based on a GeoJSON stream; I don't know which of the three or four possible ways would be most efficient for your purpose.